# How to prevent action bar and actionbar tabs from overlaying the app content

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles

In my application I have transparent action bar and transparent tabs for the viewpager layout. The problem that I have is that I can't prevent elements on visible page from hiding behind actionbar tabs. Don't know how to make paddingTop so that it will work on all devices. My current XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"

    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I too would like an answer to this. All examples show setting the paddingTop as you did above. However, it only gets the size of the ActionBar. If you have tabs below the ActionBar, the size will not include that and you content will appear below the ActionBar but behind the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this in your Base Theme:

```
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
        <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

Comment: try android:windowActionBarOverlay="false"

Comment: Last idea for you.. try adding this to your base theme:
            `<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
            <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>`